# Android Studio Start Up App Tips And Hints

Tags: android

I've looked around and I'm trying to see if Android Studio has any sort of function for when first term use of the app it shows some messages to help people.

I was thinking of using simple text boxes when on first create off the app/ first launch it would show the tips until they click on each object or item.

I know how to do the click and view just not sure the function to use for when they start the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You detect the first launch of your app for instance by loading (and defaulting) a boolean value from your app's preferences.

In your MainActivity

```
private boolean firstStart = true;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("APP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    firstStart = prefs.getBoolean("firstStart", true);

    if (firstStart) {
         // do your stuff on first start here
         // like set "showWizard" or any other flag to true so
         // your controls can behave in "firstStart" mode

         // Don't forget to save, that it is now no longer the first start...
         firstStart = false;
         SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
         editor.putBoolean("firstStart", false);
         editor.apply();

    }

}
```

Comment: Ahh I don't know why I didn't think of a boolean! Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding them into this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();    
    //put your lines in here
}
```